# Non-conformable arrays error in Regression Kriging in R

Tags: linear-regression, interpolation, linear-interpolation, kriging

Grretings to all!

In the Regression Kriging, i want to create a map for Standard Deviation of the Ordinary and the Regression Kriging.

The pH.sd (from the OK, Ordinary Kriging) are in a matrix: double [250*292]
The pH.regkrig.sd (from the RK, Regression Kriging) are in a matrix: double [1168*1312]

When i try to create the ratio: pH.regkrig.sd/pH.sd it says:

"Error in (mydata.regkrig$pH.regkrig.sd)/(mydata.krig$pH.sd) :
non-conformable arrays"

Any idea with what code i can fix it so as to plot the map?

Thanks in advance

I tried to make them same length but it failed